# Fix first_or_initialize / first_or_create races

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Basically I found that all the "first_or_initialize" / "first_or_create" calls have race condition.

#### Normal case:

```
server1: first_or_initialize -> initialize
server1: save new record
server2: first_or_initialize -> first
server2: update old record
```

#### Race case:

```
server1: first_or_initialize -> initialize
server2: first_or_initialize -> initialize
server1: save new record
server2: save new record **ERROR:  duplicate key violates unique constraint**
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Use a so-called *UPSERT* http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+upsert

Comment: This isn't limited to first_or_initialize.  You could very easily create two new records on new two servers and try to save them at the same time.  The solution to both is to catch the errors and handle appropriately.

Comment: Do you have any code example of that?